# Add Icon to the left of the title in the action bar in android

Tags: android, menu

I want to add a clickable icon/button to the left of the title in the action bar . How to do it?
Following is the code with which I have added search and setting icon to the action bar. They appear on the right. But i want to add a new icon to the left of title. How to do it?
XML :

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".ui.home.activities.TransactionSearchActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:title="categories"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings_h"
        app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Recommended way**

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_settings_24dp);// set drawable icon
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Handle icon click event

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Toast.makeText(this, "click..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also look into this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101467/c-sharp-unable-to-get-records-from-mongo-database-with-dynamic-data-containing

Comment: This answer definitely works but when using **Kotlin** use: `supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_icon)`;`supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 13):

You can do the following:

1- create your file_name.xml then Add `Toolbar`.

2- add `RelativeLayout` inside the `Toolbar`'s tag.

3- add your views i.e.(`ImageButton`,`TextView`,...)

**Note:** The `TextView` you are adding is the title of `Toolbar`.

**Sample Code: *file_name.xml***

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/products_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Title"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_24dp"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Output:**

[image: see]

Comment: The best solution.. I tried several ones.. this is the best. I am using your solution with AppBarLayout

Comment: @Muhamoud Thanks for the answer. Does file_name.xml need to be located somewhere specifically? does it need to be a menu layout file? Does it need to be inflated somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can show an icon at the left side using the following code.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | 
ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

But it wont be clickable. To make a clickable icon at the left, you need to use Toolbar instead of an action bar.

Answer (score 7):

You can replace default navigation icon (and button of cause) in following way.

Define usual UI with toolbar in your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Here goes your UI -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Then setup your Toolbar as ActionBar in onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Make toolbar show navigation button (i.e back button with arrow icon)

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.custom_icon); // Replace arrow icon with our custom icon
}
```

Handle back navigation button in onOptionsItemSelected method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            // Do whatever you want

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
```

The same in Kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) // Important step, we enable button on the left side of the toolbar

        toolbar.navigationIcon = getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_icon) // Here we change default navigation button icon

    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                doSomething() // Here we can perform any action
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    private fun doSomething() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: Android Toolbar add icon before title]

Comment: Fix mistake:  android:id="@id/toolbar" ->  android:id="@+id/toolbar"

Answer (score 3):

One thing is that by default title and app icon set into the left  and other than icons sent into the right side. If you want to add your icons into the left side there is a way to them into to left side which is:

**step 1.** create a custom layout which having search, setting icon and your title as you want.

**step 2.** create a toolBar layout like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="#ECA539"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

**step 3.** inflate your custom layout into the toolbar like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
initToolbar();

}
private void initToolBar() {
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    View customlayout= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    toolbar.addView(logo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is updated era of Android, You must go for Toolbar so that you can do any kind of customization with the help of xml. Instead of using menu i would suggest to use toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffffa302"
    android:minHeight="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pinterest_pin"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And through code you can handle event

Comment: I want my bar to have the title , a clickable icon on left and 2 icons in the rightmost space. I am new to android. Can u tell me that how can i achieve this with toolbar?

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar  and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html - Read these blogs, will help you to get clear understanding of toolbar

Answer (score 1):

I always like to put a AppBarLayout that I can control the way the toolbar appears

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarAddPlan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnAddPlanTourClose"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/close_circle_outline" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

That way a can put more elements and arrange them like I want. In this case insert a left icon to close the activity by a fragment.

So in the fragment a do this

```
 //That is in the Fragment
setupToolbar(R.id.toolbarAddPlan,getString(R.string.addPlanTour),true)





//It is in na Kotlin Extansion file.



 inline fun Fragment.setupToolbar(@IdRes id: Int, title:String?= null, upNavigation: Boolean = false) : ActionBar {

    val activityCompat = activity as AppCompatActivity
    val toolbar = activity?.findViewById<Toolbar>(id)
    activityCompat.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    if(title != null){
        activityCompat.supportActionBar?.title = title
    }
    activityCompat.supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
    return activityCompat.supportActionBar!!
}
```

The result will be something like this:

[image]

The action "SALVAR" i put via inflat menu

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater?.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_plan_tour,menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return when (item?.itemId){
            R.id.menuPlanTourSave ->{
                true
            }else ->return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }

    }
```

Menu XML layout src/menu/menu_add_plan_tour.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuPlanTourSave"
        android:title="@string/btnSave"
        android:tooltipText="@string/btnSave"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btnSave"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/btnSave"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            />


    </item>
</menu>
```

And do not forget to use  setHasOptionsMenu(true) to enable the menu.