# How to align logo to the left size in action bar?

Tags: java, android

I have an issue with aligning logo to the left in action bar.Currently now it is align in center (by default?).  Do you know any solution that might help?

Thank you

I also  tried to insert logo using Image View and tried to align using "gravity=left" but none of this worked.

This is my toolbar_main.xml

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:logo="@drawable/cookme_logo">
```

This is my activity_home.xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

This is ActivityHome.java

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    ((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)).setLogo(R.drawable.cookme_logo);
```

This is AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/cookme_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/cookme_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".ActivityHome">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle this. Please check that you are implementing correct theme. Or you can add custom template inside <toolbar>. So you can design your toolbar the way you want it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using this

```
ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`


your question is probably answered here :


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713859/add-icon-to-the-left-of-the-title-in-the-action-bar-in-android
```

Comment: It displays only my name of the app and back button, but unfortunately it does not display my logo

Comment: in the link provided there are other options which could fit your problem, if none of the answers provided works I will take a better look on this

Comment: I managed to display using Toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.custom_logo).I think the issue why it does not display on the left side is because of resolution of logo

Answer (score 0):

In your `toolbar_main.xml` insert these lines

```
        app:logo="@drawable/cookme_logo"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="8dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

if you use `app:logo` you don't need to set the logo in `ActivityHome.java`.